# What does the second "幅” mean in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

...真是一幅"幅"美丽的山水画...
VS
...真是一幅美丽的山水画...

I am having some problems figuring out why there is a second ”幅” in the sentence and what it means? If I took out the second "幅” what would the meaning then be in comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"一幅幅" in "一幅幅美丽的山水画" mainly means 'one after another', (indicates plural by extended logic)

一幅幅 is short for 一幅又一幅 or 一幅接一幅 (one after another)

"一幅幅美丽的山水画" means "one beautiful landscape painting after another'

Other examples of double classifier signifing 'one after another':

> **一個**愚蠢的決定 - **a** stupid decision
>
> **一個個**愚蠢的決定 - **one** stupid decision **after another**

~

> **一個**寒冷的冬天 - **a** cold winter
>
> **一個個**寒冷的冬天 - **one** cold winter **after another**

~

> **一位**革命英雄 - **a** revolutionary hero
>
> **一位位**革命英雄 - **one** revolutionary hero **after another**

~

> 沿途看見**一座**酒莊 - saw **a** winery along the way
>
> 沿途看見**一座座**酒莊 - saw **one** winery **after another** along the way

'One after another' can describe 'a group of things or people at one time' or 'one individual after another individual across time or distance'

To simply indicate plural, you can use '幾' or '數' as in "幾幅美丽的山水画"

Answer (score 1):

一幅幅 means plural.

If you took out the second 幅, it would mean there is only one beautiful picture.

Note:

You can not always express plural by doubling it.

我画了一幅幅画 (wrong)

一幅幅画呈现出来 (right)

Comment: Can you clarify the circumstances under which you _can_ pluralize by doing this?

Comment: @StumpyJoePete, Sorry, it is a little complicated, I can not summarize it as simple rules.

Answer (score 1):

一幅幅 is to make a general reference,you will not ask what picture or which one,they are just some kind pictures.