# Why does 一幅幅图画, not 一幅图画?

Tags: grammar, measure-word

In the following sentence:

> 于是，每天晚上，秀春都拉着丈夫坐在灯下，指着识字课本的**一幅幅图画**问丈夫。

It means:

> Therefore, on every night Xiuchun lets her husband sit under the light, points to the literacy book's 一幅幅图画 to ask him what they are.

I think 一 is an amount and 幅 is a 量词. But I don't understand why it is 一幅幅, not 一幅.

So what makes them different?

Comment: to repeat a 量詞 indicates plural people or items and there are always many of them. In addition, it emphasizes individuality and equal importance.

Comment: Tang Ho has explained the meaning of 一幅幅 pretty well. 

It's also worth to know that those words and expressions (每天晚上, 都拉着, 一幅幅图画) the author used convey that 秀春 study hard and diligently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From  a previously asked question [What does the second "幅” mean in the following sentence?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/25785/what-does-the-second-%e5%b9%85-mean-in-the-following-sentence/25787#25787)

> 一幅幅 is short for 一幅又一幅 or 一幅接一幅 (one after another)
>
> "一幅幅美丽的山水画" means "one beautiful landscape painting after another'
>
> 'One after another' can describe 'a group of things or people at one time' or 'one individual after another individual across time or distance'

- "指着识字课本的(***一幅***)(图画)问丈夫" =  "points at (***a***) (picture) in the literacy book and asks her husband.
- "指着识字课本的(***一幅幅*** 图画)问丈夫" =  "points at (***one*** picture ***after another***) in the literacy book, and asks her husband."

**Update:**

There are additional rules about reduplicated classifiers I want to make clear.

一幅幅图画 does mean 'one picture after another' but that's when the object is not confined by boundaries; When the object is confined by boundaries, the reduplicated classifiers indicates 'each and everyone'

Example:

'一位位英雄' = 'one hero after another'

'在这个大厅里的一位位英雄' = 'each and every hero in this hall' (the objects are confined by boundaries within this hall'

'一滴滴雨点' = 'one raindrop after another'

'在那片叶子上的一滴滴雨点' = 'each and every raindrop on that leaf' (the objects are confined by boundaries within that leaf'

In '指着识字课本的一幅幅图画' , '课本的一幅幅图画' should indicate 'each and every picture', but the verb '指着' (pointing at) indicates an action that can only be done one at a time, therefore, it is clear that the sentence means pointing at one picture after another.

For the same reason, '指着大厅里的一位位英雄' would mean 'pointing at one hero after another in the hall'

> *i*s this rule applicable to all 量词?

The answer is no. We use classifiers because most of them roughly describe the shape, size and form of the object. 一片雲, 一團雲 give us the idea of what form of cloud we are talking about; 一個橙, 一籃橙 give us the idea of what form of orange we are talking about.

However, some classifiers do not describe the shape, size and form of the object. One good example is '名' . We do not say '一名名好漢' because 一名(a name of) doesn't describe the shape, size and form of a human, it is too abstract to be associated with a vivid image of a man.

Comment: Thanks and is this rule applicable to all 量词?

Comment: Mostly  applicable to all 量词 but there's always exceptions. The only one I can think of now is  一名名男子,

Comment: @Blaszard I have updated my answer, added some more info, you might like to take a look

Answer (score 0):

一幅幅图画 pictures (one by one)

一幅图画  a picture